# Ef Core DbContext tracking across multiple HTTP requests

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have my own simple framework for routing/controllers in C# and .NET Core. I'm using EF Core for the ORM. In Startup.cs I'm configuring it like so:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
        {

            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            options.UseSqlServer(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION"));
        });
    }
```

I'm using dependency injection to get an instance of my DbContext. In my controller actions I do the following:

*Action 1*:

1. Do not use `AsNoTracking()` on my queries
2. Make changes to a model instance
3. Do not save changes

*Action 2 (another HTTP request)*:

1. Do literally anything
2. Run `SaveChangesAsync()`on DbContext

The changes made in *Action 1* are then persisted. If I severed any relations in *Action 1* then I get an error.

I know that by default DbContext is scoped. Do I have to implement some of my own scoping code to ensure that I get a new instance with each HTTP request?

NOTE: I am NOT using MVC, I am using my own little library that I'm developing. I just learned that MVC probably uses IServiceScopeFactory to generate scopes. I am not sure how to use it in middleware though.

Comment: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#entity-framework-contexts) says :"Entity Framework contexts should be added to the service container using the scoped lifetime". You could add your DbContext as a Singeton service, but I can assure you you will live to regret it.

Comment: @yorodm Adding as a singleton is the opposite of what the OP wants

Comment: sounds like you've some how registered your db context as a singleton, or this is occuring on the same request

Comment: @johnny5 He wants his instance of dbContext to live among requests (Those are the actions he describes) won't get that with a "new instance" since that's what "scoped" gives you already. Same instance means singleton lifetime, unless you implement your own lifetime strategy

Comment: @yorodm, those two actions are describing the behavior he is currently exhibiting, the bottom of the questions ask `how to ensure they can get a new instance with each HTTP request`

Comment: @johnny5 O.o you're totally right, he **did** registered as a singleton!?! But how?

Comment: @yorodm I feel like we're missing a piece of the code, or this isn't happen in 2 requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181237/discussion-between-yorodm-and-johnny-5).

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here's how to wrap a scope with HttpContext in a middleware:

```
public class Middleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public Middleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            context.RequestServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            // Do whatever you want here
            if (_next != null)
                await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a hack, there should be a way to configure your DI to provide you with a scope

Comment: A scope with each HTTP request though? Seems like this is something that needs to be manually put in depending on where exactly you want the scope to be.

Comment: You could probably skip a step and just request the factory via DI though.

Comment: by default .net core should provide you with a new context per http request, by default.  You must be missing sometihng important from you setup

Comment: I'm going to try just using context.RequestServices instead and come back with an update later.

Comment: context.RequestServices is null in middleware. :(

Comment: please upload your full startup.cs in the original problem

Comment: I figured it out. Don't return a task. Await whatever tasks you're going to be doing. I'll update my answer to get rid of that bug.